# Why is the performance for this Java code so inconsistent?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I'm running a small test that although is a micro benchmark does mimic what we are actually doing in production pretty well.

I'm creating a 2D array, 5 columns and 10,000,000 rows filled with random integers between 0-19 inclusive. I then want to sum up all the numbers in the 3rd column as long as the value in the 2nd column is even. I do this 100 times to warm up and then another 100 times and time how long it takes.

On my machine the vast majority of time it takes around 9 seconds, however, occasionally it takes just under 6 seconds.

It doesn't look like garbage collection, or JIT compilation.

Does anyone have any idea why it would be so significantly faster very occasionally?

I run the code with JDK7u11 on Linux with these arguments: -server -XX:+PrintCompilation -Xms500m -Xmx500m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails however, using various different JDKs (from 6 all the way to 8) and removing all these parameters doesn't seem to effect the timings significantly.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaPerformanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numColumns = 5;
        int numRows = 10000000;
        int[][] data = new int[numColumns][numRows];
        Random rand = new Random(1234);
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                data[j][i] = rand.nextInt(20);
            }
        }
        int warmUp = 100;
        ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("warm up " + warmUp + " times");
        long warmUpStart = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < warmUp; i++) {
            sums.add(sum(numRows, data));
        }
        long warmUpEnd = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("warm up complete " + (warmUpEnd - warmUpStart) / 1000000);
        int numberOfRuns = 100;
        int finalSum = 0;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRuns; i++) {
            finalSum = sum(numRows, data);
        }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long diff = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + diff + "    Sum: " + finalSum);
    }


    public static int sum(int numRows, int[][] columnBased) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            if ((columnBased[1][i] % 2) == 0) {
                sum += columnBased[2][i];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Thanks, Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible causes for slow performance including cache misses and failed branch prediction.  I would make sure your code is optimal and then repeat it to ensure you result is stable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaPerformanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numColumns = 5;
        int numRows = 10000000;
        byte[][] data = new byte[numColumns][numRows];
        Random rand = new Random(1234);
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                data[j][i] = (byte) rand.nextInt(20);
            }
        }
        int warmUp = 10;
        ArrayList<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("warm up " + warmUp + " times");
        long warmUpStart = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < warmUp; i++) {
            sums.add(sum(numRows, data));
        }
        long warmUpEnd = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("warm up complete " + (warmUpEnd - warmUpStart) / 1000000);
        for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++) {
            int numberOfRuns = 100;
            int finalSum = 0;
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRuns; i++) {
                finalSum = sum(numRows, data);
            }
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long diff = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
            System.out.println("Time taken: " + diff + "    Sum: " + finalSum);
        }
    }


    public static int sum(int numRows, byte[][] columnBased) {
        int sum = 0;
        byte[] col1 = columnBased[1];
        byte[] col2 = columnBased[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            // use multiplication instead of "if" to avoid branch prediction failures
            sum += ((col1[i] + 1) & 1) * col2[i];
        return sum;
    }
}
```

prints

```
warm up 10 times
warm up complete 109
Time taken: 1006    Sum: 47505460
Time taken: 1006    Sum: 47505460
Time taken: 1026    Sum: 47505460
```

In summary: optimising the code will improve the performance far more than playing with command line parameters.